# How to hide password shown by browser on failing to get URL through window login pop up using Selenium WebDriver with C# language?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to login window login popup (e.g., http://Username:Password@SiteURL) but when i am fail to load the url due to network disconnection then browser is showing password of site

Comment: Such way of authentication is deprecated because of lack of safety. Instead you should send your traffic through a proxy that would be adding required authentication headers to all the requests.

Comment: okay.. can you help me with code for it ?